# Speeding up a query on a large database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm pretty new to SQL and databases in general so any advice or guidance is appreciated.

I'm searching through a large database (750000+ rows) and displaying them on a webpage (25 at a time).  My problem is that when you search through the database with specific parameters, lets say `SENT_DATE` for an email, it takes around 5-6 minutes.  I assume that it's going through all the rows and making the comparison which is why it's taking so long.  Also keep in mind that I don't believe this table is sorted.

Is there any way to speed up the search or is it something I'm just gonna have to accept?

Comment: [Database Indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) are *the* primary implementation that make relational databases fast: they trade space and maintenance costs for *significantly* faster filtering (and ordering) in queries that can utilize said indices efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index on the column `SENT_DATE` and avoid functions that make index usage impossible. After adding the index your query should look something like this for instance

```
select * from your_table
where SENT_DATE between '2014-06-04' and '2014-06-05'
```

or

```
select * from your_table
where SENT_DATE > '2014-06-04'
```

That should only take a few milliseconds.